# Access overridden class variable in parent of subclass

Tags: python

How to I access a class variable that I expect a subclass to replace?

this is what i want to acchieve:

```
class Foo():
    var = "Foo"
    @staticmethod
    def print_var():
    print(Foo.var)

class Bar(Foo):
    var = "Bar"

>> Bar.print_var()
>> "Bar
```

The code above prints "Foo" instead of "Bar"

Comment: Why are you using a static method then?

Comment: I would like to access it without creating an instance. Is this a bad approach?

I'm trying to DRY up some code

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Don't use `staticmethod`. *At the very least* use [`@classmethod` decorator](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#classmethod) here:

```
class Foo():
    var = "Foo"

    @classmethod
    def print_var(cls):
        print(cls.var)

class Bar(Foo):
    var = "Bar"
```

This makes `print_var` accessible on the class, but is passed a reference to the current class so you can look up `var` on the 'right' object.

Use `staticmethod` only if you want to remove all context from a method, turning it into a regular function again.

Demo:

```
>>> class Foo():
...     var = "Foo"
...     @classmethod
...     def print_var(cls):
...         print(cls.var)
... 
>>> class Bar(Foo):
...     var = "Bar"
... 
>>> Bar.print_var()
Bar
>>> Foo.print_var()
Foo
```

Comment: Beat me to it, you've got a wee typo in `classmethod`

Comment: Thank you! The lines between the two have been a bit fuzzy for me.

Answer (score 2):

Use a `classmethod`:

```
class Foo():
    @classmethod
    def print_var(cls):
        print(cls.var)
```