# Python class inheritance: dynamic subclass initialization with own and parent defaults and init methods

Tags: python, oop, inheritance, subclass

I'm trying to create a system of classes that can be initialized with **kwargs and have default values for each field. Here is some code representing what I'm trying to do:

```
class Parent(object): #should only have p_var fields
    DEFAULTS = {
    "p_var_1" : "my name",
    "p_var_2" : 2
    }

    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        for key in DEFAULTS:
            #Also include check for list type and copy, not assign
            if key in kwargs:
                setattr(self, key, kwargs[key])
            else:
                setattr(self, key, self.DEFAULTS[key])
        #Check for super being 'object' - problems?
        #if not super() == object:
        #   super().__init__(**kwargs)


class Gen1(Parent): #should have p_var and G1_var fields
    DEFAULTS = {
    "G1_var_1" : "Generation 1",
    "G1_var_2" : []
    }

    #redefining only in case if Parent can't check for super
    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        for key in DEFAULTS:
            #Also include check for list type and copy, not assign
            if key in kwargs:
                setattr(self, key, kwargs[key])
            else:
                setattr(self, key, self.DEFAULTS[key])

        #check whether super() is object
        super().__init__(**kwargs) #pass all args to parent init 

class Gen2(Gen1): #should have p_var, G1_var and G2_var fields
    DEFAULTS = {
    "G2_var_1" : 1337,
    "G2_var_2" : (10,4)
    }

    #After Gen1, redefining __init__ shouldn't be necessary
```

So that after setting a couple of instances:

```
Gen2item1 = Gen2()
Gen2item2 = Gen2(p_var_1 = "different name", G2_var_1 = 666)
```

Gen2item1 would be initialized to all default values:

- Gen2item1.p_var_1 is "my name"
- Gen2item1.p_var_2 is 2
- Gen2item1.G1_var_1 is "Generation 1"
- Gen2item1.G1_var_2 is [] (copy)
- Gen2item1.G2_var_1 is 1337 and
- Gen2item1.G2_var_2 is (10,4)

but Gen2item1 would have different p_var_1 and G2_var_1 values, with the rest being the same.
However, since the 'DEFAULT' is overriden in children classes, the Gen2item1 values:

- Gen2item1.p_var_1 is 666
- Gen2item1.p_var_2 is (10,4)

are set three times, by each generation (level), and `G1_var` or `p_var` values are not set. For Gen2item2 the G2_var_1 is set to 666 and G2_var_2 to (10,4) by all three generations of `__init__`.

---

So the bottom line question is about a way to make some 'defaults' field (dict) for each class generation so that:

1. Upon calling a subclass's `__init__` via `item = subclass()`, it would grab the arguments from `kwargs` depending on the 'defaults' dict's keys,
2. Set its own fields via `setattrib(self, key, value)`, taking the values from kwargs if the key from defaults is present, otherwise take value from defaults aswell, and
3. Call its parent's init while passing the kwargs to that via `super()__init__(**kwargs)`.

The parent then sets the defaults defined by its generation's dict the same way for the same instance of the subclass, calls and passes to its own parent's `__init__`, and so on until the parent is `object`, in which case the `super().__init__` simply doesn't get called/passed arguments to.
I have read about metaclasses, which seem overkill, and [got my hopes high on this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24693675/access-overridden-class-variable-in-parent-of-subclass), which has a separate instance for parent and subclass.
Is there a way to achieve something like this without metaclasses? Would it be better to store the default values in an external global dict of dicts (in this case some help with addressing would be appreciated), or is there a way to set up a factory?

---

Solved edit:
The `__init_subclass__` works and pretty much does what I want, provided that it also defines `__init__` for the class to be initialized (specific detail for my project). That serves as an answer to my question and provided some useful info for how to achieve the setup I want in my project. I believe it would be sufficient to define a classmethod that sets up an appropriate `__init__` and have it run when class is defined (which is what the very new `__init_subclass__` seems to do so helpfully), but to have at least some backward-compatibility, it seems metaclass is the way to do that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the new classmethod added to `object()` in Python 3.6: [`__init_subclass__`](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0487/)

This method is called when the class is subclassed and allows you to customize the subclasses' creation without using a metaclass.

Your example would look like this:

```
class Base:
    def __init_subclass__(cls, **kwargs):
        super().__init_subclass__()
        for key, value in kwargs.items():
            setattr(cls, key, value)

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super().__init__()
        for key, value in kwargs.items():
            setattr(self, key, value)     

class Parent(Base, p_var_1='my_name', p_var_2=2):
    pass

class Gen1(Parent, G1_var_1='Generation 1', G1_var_2=[]):
    pass

class Gen2(Gen1, G2_var_1=1337, G2_var_2=(10,4)):
    pass
```

Comment: This works for setting defaults, but it seems I still have to define `__init__` to change the values upon creating an instance, since using this code as-is throws a TypeError when doing something like `g1 = Gen1(G1_var_1 = "asdf")`

Comment: By setting up an `__init__` creator function in the `__init_subclass__`, it seems that what I wanted to do works. After some testing, if no problems arise, will mark this as answer.

Comment: Yes, the example was too skeletal. It was intended only to show the `__init_subclass__` method. You're right: `__init_subclass__` is called to create the subclass but it's needed an `__init__` if you want to pass arguments (positional or named) in the instantiation. I've updated the code.

Answer (score 0):

I would skip the `DEFAULTS` dicts as unnecessary bloat. If you really need access to the default values for those parameters, you can get them by introspecting the `__init__` methods. Otherwise, the general rule for using `super` is to strip off the arguments that are unique to your class, and pass all others to the next call to `__init__`.

It is the class designer's responsibility to make sure any classes in the resulting MRO remove all arguments to `__init__` before `object.__init__` gets called. In the example below, the only way `Parent.__init__` will call `object.__init__` with actual arguments is if some *other* class in the MRO of `self` fails to remove its arguments.

```
class Parent(object):
    def __init__(self, p_var_1="my name", p_var_2=2, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(**kwargs)
        self.p_var_1 = p_var_1
        self.p_var_2 = p_var_2

class Gen1(Parent): #should have p_var and G1_var fields
    def __init__(self, g1_var_1="Generation 1", g1_var_2=None, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(**kwargs)
        if g1_var_2 is None:
            g1_var_2 = []
        self.g1_var_1 = g1_var_1
        self.g1_var_2 = g1_var_2

class Gen2(Gen1): #should have p_var, G1_var and G2_var fields
    def __init__(self, g2_var_1=1337, g2_var_2=(10,4), **kwargs):
        super().__init__(**kwargs)
        self.g2_var_1 = g2_var_1
        self.g2_var_2 = g2_var_2
```

Consider a call like

```
Gen2(p_var_1=...,
     p_var_2=...,
     g1_var_1=...,
     g1_var_2=...,
     g2_var_1=...,
     g2_var_2=...)
```

The first method called is `Gen2.__init__`, which will pass on only `p` and `g1` vars to `super.__init__`. That call results in a call to `Gen1.__init__`, which passes on only `p` variables on. When `Parent.__init__` is called, `**kwargs` is empty.

Comment: I would also, however like to have some fool-proofing in the setup, such as testing for the type of the variable, and reverting to default if the type is inappropriate, or ignoring an unexpected keyword argument, preferably without creating a massive __init__ for each of the classes for cases when it adds a lot of arguments. The way I try to do it now is by having (external) dicts, one for default values and another for tuples of acceptable types, for each of the classes.

Comment: You shouldn't silently replace a value of the wrong type; if it's not valid to use, that should be treated as an error. As for unexpected keyword arguments, you can't really assume that just because *your* class isn't expecting an argument that it shouldn't be passed on to a class farther along in the MRO.